# ¿Como imprimir grafico con onload="window.print()?

Tags: php, html

Tengo el siguiente codigo

```
    <?php

    if(isset($_GET['mod']))
    {
        require_once 'PSController.php';

        $fecha_actual   = date("d-m-Y");
        $fecha          = date("d-m-Y",strtotime($fecha_actual."- 1 days")); 

        $ps = new PSController();

        $PDP_ContextImprimir            = $ps->PDP_ContextImprimir();
    }
?>
```

```
<h2 class="text-center">Reportes <?php echo $fecha; ?></h2>

    <!-- GRAFICOS !-->
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <div id="grafico1">

            <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
            <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
            <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
            <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript">

                chartCPU = new Highcharts.chart('grafico1', 
                {
                    chart: {
                        type: 'line'
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'PDP Context 3G'
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        gridLineWidth: 1,
                        categories: 
                        [
                            <?php
                                foreach($PDP_ContextImprimir['LABEL'] as $hora)
                                {
                                    echo "'$hora',";
                                }
                            ?>
                        ]
                    },
                    yAxis: 
                    [
                        {
                            min: 0,
                            title: 
                            {
                                text: '',
                            }

                        }, 

                        {
                            min: 0,
                            max: 100,
                            title: 
                            {
                                text: '',
                            },
                            opposite: true
                        }
                    ],
                    plotOptions: {
                        column: {
                            pointPadding: 0.2,
                            borderWidth: 0
                        }
                    },
                    credits: {
                      enabled: false
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        split: true
                    },
                    series: 
                    [
                        {
                            name: 'RATE',
                            yAxis: 1,
                            data: 
                            [
                                <?php 
                                    for ($j=0; $j < count($PDP_ContextImprimir['SUCC_RATE']) ; $j++) 
                                    { 
                                        echo $PDP_ContextImprimir['SUCC_RATE'][$j].',';
                                    }
                                ?>
                            ],
                            cursor: 'pointer'
                        },{
                            name: 'REQUEST',
                            yAxis: 0,
                            data: 
                            [
                                <?php 
                                    for ($k=0; $k < count($PDP_ContextImprimir['REQUEST']) ; $k++) 
                                    { 
                                        echo $PDP_ContextImprimir['REQUEST'][$k].','; 
                                    }
                                ?>
                            ],
                            cursor: 'pointer'
                        },{
                            name: 'SUCCESS',
                            yAxis: 0,
                            data: 
                            [
                                <?php 
                                    for ($p=0; $p < count($PDP_ContextImprimir['SUCCESS']) ; $p++) 
                                    { 
                                        echo $PDP_ContextImprimir['SUCCESS'][$p].',';
                                    }
                                ?>
                            ],
                            cursor: 'pointer'
                        }
                    ]
                });

            </script>

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END GRAFICOS !-->
```

Lo quiero hacer es imprimir esa pagina con **body onload="window.print();"** logro que me imprima pero no me muestra las lineas del gráfico y si quieto el **onload="window.print();"** el grafico esta bien con sus lineas perfecta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No te funciona en el evento `onload` del `body` porque necesitas que se carguen los datos de tu chart para poder luego imprimir, por consiguiente puedes escuchar el evento `onload` del `chart` y ahi disparar la acción de imprimir.

Intenta cambiar el inicio de la declaración de tu Chart:

```
chartCPU = new Highcharts.chart('grafico1', 
{
   events:
   {
      load: function(){
         window.print();
      }
   }
//A partir de aqui si puedes seguir con tu declaración
```

Si quieres imprimir el grafico especificamente debes revisar que tengas incluido este script:

Y Cambiaria las lineas de codigo de arriba por las siguientes:

```
chartCPU = new Highcharts.chart('grafico1', 
{
   events:
   {
      load: function(){
         setTimeout(function(){
            chartCPU.print();
         }, 1000);
      }
   }
//A partir de aqui si puedes seguir con tu declaración
```

Puedes comprobar que funcione en este [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ub0kjmo5/)

Comment: Si porque el grafico me aparece pero no me pinta las lineas.. 

Tengo este archivo "imprimir.php" en ese archivo hago lo del codigo que coloque en la pregunta, pero este archivo se va abrir mediante un bottom que yo lo llamo.. Me explico ?

Comment: No entendi bien, pero si cambias tu codigo por lo que te puse que sucede????

Comment: Mira tengo esto "<a href="controllers/ProbandoController.php?mod=imprimir" target="_blank" class="btn btn-success">Imprimir</a>" en donde hay me llama el archivo que contiene el codigo que puse arriba.

Comment: Amigo. ¿Estas?,

Comment: A ver esa parte la entendi, ahora en tu pagina ProbandoController.php no tienes el javascript que crea el grafico????

Comment: Si hay se crea el grafico pero quiero que se cree todo tanto la grafica como todo lo que se muestra en la pagina ProbandoController.php

Comment: El codigo javascript de esa pagina es lo que pones en tu pregunta????

Comment: Si todo ese codigo que coloco es de ese archivo

Comment: Entonces donde radica el problema, si cambias el body onload="window.print();" por lo que te comente??????

Comment: No me imprime nada, si quito el onload en el body

Comment: Men y mi respuesta no lo has aplicado????? para algo te la puse has intentado hacer lo que te dije en ella??????

Comment: No me funciona bro

Comment: Pero que hace te da error, te muestra algo en la consola, dame datos para poder ayudarte mejor